# Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception while installing Linux from USB drive

Tags: linux, boot, usb, graphics-card

I am looking for help to resolve a persistent "not syncing" panic stop while trying to install Rocky Linux 9.1 from a USB drive.

### Context

The machine is currently running 9.1 without any issues but I'm now planning a fresh re-install of 9.1 in order to put it into service as a KVM/QEMU host.

### Hardware

- M/B: ASUS Prime X570-P
- CPU: Ryzen 5 5600X 4th Gen 6-core
- RAM: Crucial Ballistix 3600 MHz DDR4 DRAM (2x16GB)
- SSD: SAMSUNG 980 PRO 1TB PCIe NVMe Gen4
- VGA: ATI AMD FirePro 2270 512MB PCI-E

### Things I have tried

- Using different USB drives.
- Removing the two 16GB RAM sticks and using only one at a time.
- Removing all cards except for the video card used for the console.

I have no experience with debugging kernel panic stops and have had no luck searching this forum nor googling the net for solutions.

### UEFI BIOS Settings

- "Factory" settings
- Secure boot disabled
- Never overclocked; RAM running at 2666MHz

### The Panic

I suspect a video driver issue even though the video vard works fine for the console when I boot the existing Rocky 9.1 installation. A photo of the panic screen follows:
[image]

Comment: Please do not [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1757044/revisions) to add an “update” that is an answer. What you did by [posting an actual answer](https://superuser.com/a/1757053/167207) is 100% fine and the way self-solved questions should be answered.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the issue occurs only with the Rocky Linux 9,1 release. Rocky Rocky Linux 9.0 installs fine from a USB.